# MFA using PKI certificates

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, smartcard, software

I'm trying to set up a multi factor authentication using PKIs certificates.
A PKI infrastructure is ready to use and i'm planning to put these certificates on smart cards.
I was looking for a smart card reader and I came across this one :
https://www.amazon.ca/-/fr/Gemalto-Idbridge-CT30-USB-lecteur-carte/dp/B00G46Y7CG?language=en_CA
My question is : Do I need software to put certificates on my cards?
Thank you.

Comment: Of course you need some kind of software. Certificates don't magically arrive at the smart card without any software being involved. If the necessary software is already in your systems or if you need to install or even buy additional software is unknown though. Details can depend both on the brand of  smart cards and on the hardware you use to interact with the smart cards.

Comment: My question was poorly asked yeah, what I wanted to say is "Does that smart card reader have an integrated software or do I need to buy one?. It seems that there is none. So, would you recommend some software please?

Comment: Smart card reader is often a generic PnP device and OS will likely have drivers for it. You will need a software to work with smart card itself, not reader. Smart card vendors provide required software to interact with their cards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I want to use these : https://en.cryptoshop.com/gemalto-idprime-md-3940.html?SID=23tnn9ps7578hconq2o2ae0rl5&___store=english&___from_store=default, a software is included? It seems so but I want to be sure. (Im sorry I've never worked with smart cards before so I don't really know)

Comment: The PnP may fail to work (my actual experience) so I would look for a reader that has a good support and working driver. As for recommendations, this is agains the stack exchange rules to recommend a commercial software. Otherwise I could sell you ready to go sollution.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually more to putting certificates on the card than just a software. You have two options when putting certificates on the card:

1. The private key is generated on the card alongside with the CSR that is sent to the CA for signing and the cert is then installed on the card. This is the preferred option for authentication certificates, the fact that the private key is on the chip and can't be extracted provides additional security.
2. The keystore is generated outside of the card (including private key) and the keystore is then pushed to the smart card (installed). This is the preferred option for private keys that may require archival (e.g Mail encryption certificates that you want to use to decrypt your old emails). Private key must be generated outside of the smartcard as the one generated on the card can't be extracted (for archival).

Usual process of getting certificates on the smart card consists of two steps:

1. Pre-personalisation (some vendors deliver blank cards that require this step on your side, others take care of it for you as a part of solution they're selling) of the card where:

   - the firmware is installed on the card (different cards allow different versions of the firmware, each with different functions and capabilities)
   - generation of the private keys (this is sometimes done as a part of personalisation
   - generation of the PIN/PUK and operator PIN (pin used to access the card for administration purposes like installation of the certificates, key generation and certificate removal)
2. Personalisation of the card, this step involves:

   - generation of the CSR (if key is stored on the card) or creation of the keystore (with the private key and CSR) if the private key can exist outside
   - issuance of the certificate
   - installation of the certificate or the keystore on the card
   - generation/change of the PIN may be part of this process

So your question is not only if you need a software for the installation of the certificates. Depending on the type of the card you have, you need to know if they are pre-personalised (do you need to install firmware on them or not) if yes which version of the firmware is required and how do you go about the installation. If the cards is pre-personalised by the vendor, then you most likely need vendor specific software to generate the key and CSR and install the certificate. On top of that you need a card reader/printer capable of writing to the card and its driver. From my experience the drivers provided by MS are often having trouble writing to the cards.

Considering that you are creating MFA system, the key should be generated on the card, you may consider automating the issuance process with your CA to make it one smooth operation.

You should also think about PIN encryption and how you are going to take care of that (the PIN on the card should be encrypted) and many more things.

Short answer to your question is: yes you need a software.